# How do I run a command as root?

Tags: software-installation

I've downloaded a driver for a video card (*.run) and tried to install within a terminal. When I started the installation process I got this error: `ERROR: nvidia-installer must be run as root`. I'm logged in with my own profile.

Answer (score 4):

If you have an administrator account, simply

```
sudo command
```

runs `commands` as root after asking your password (for safety).

If your account is not an administrator account, you can't :-).

Notice: in a standard Ubuntu installation, the user you set up in the installation process is an administrator account. Guest account is not. Other users, depends on how you create them.

Notice too: "administrator" account in this context mean an account which has the privilege to become root. There is a lot more info in https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RootSudo and in https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Sudoers. I am using the simple "administrator account here" because it's how it's called in the graphic interface to create a new user:

[image: Adding a user with administrative capabilities]

Comment: when i log in i have 3 accounts -My,guest and remote access.I log in whith my accont (owner) is this not the same administrator?

Comment: It's how it's called when you create a new user via the now unfortunately ultraminimalist graphic interface... it means being in the %admin or %sudo group (depend on how your sudoers file is written). I will edit to specify.