# Uninstalling mailarchiva from Ubuntu

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, uninstall

New to Linux here. 
I installed mailarchiva on ubuntu 19.10 a few days ago, only to discover that Google cannot find any uninstall instructions anywhere for it. In the mailarchiva installation folder, there is one text file called `uninstall` that says I should run this bash script, but I do not know how to run bash scripts.

Has anyone ever tried this? Will it remove only mailarchiva and leave everything else alone?

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
# MailArchiva Enterprise Edition Uninstall Script
# Copyright (c) 2005-2009 Jamie Band
# Visit http://www.mailarchiva.com for more information on this product
# change below with caution! 
# the contents of MAILARCHIVA_HOME will be deleted
WEBAPPNAME=ROOT
MAILARCHIVA_HOME=/opt/mailarchiva
SERVER=$MAILARCHIVA_HOME/server
CATALINA_BASE=/var/opt/mailarchiva/tomcat
WEBAPP=$CATALINA_BASE/webapps/$WEBAPPNAME
AUTOUPDATE=$CATALINA_BASE/update/autoupdate
echo MailArchiva Uninstall
if [ `id -u` != "0" ]; then
        echo "Sorry, you are not root."
        exit 1
fi
echo -n "Are you sure you wish to uninstall MailArchiva (yes/no)? "
read proceed
if [ "$proceed" == "yes" ]; then 
 $SERVER/stopserver 2>/dev/null
 mkdir ./backup 2>/dev/null
 $SERVER/uninstallservice 2>/dev/null
 rm -rf $MAILARCHIVA_HOME 
 rm -rf $WEBAPP
 rm -rf $AUTOUPDATE
 rm -rf $CATALINA_BASE/work
 rm -rf $CATALINA_BASE/logs
 echo MailArchiva is uninstalled.
 echo FYI: If you experienced problems, please report to 
support@mailarchiva.com
else
 echo "aborted."
fi
```

Comment: Related: [How do I run .sh scripts?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/38661/how-do-i-run-sh-scripts) and [How do I run a command as root?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/371027/how-do-i-run-a-command-as-root)

Answer (score 1):

Based on what you've posted, this script should complete what you're looking for. From the terminal, in the directory where the script lives, run this:

```
sudo ./uninstall
```

Comment: Done, thank you. The script completed without errors, but I can still find files in those mailarchiva directories.

How does one purge them?